# Error: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders

Tags: javascript, html, ml5.js

StackOverflow community, I am new to machine learning especially ml5.js and p5.js library, I have encountered the error below and I tried to search but still not able to figure out what's wrong with the code. Hope that you could give me some ideas. Thanks in advance!

The error I have encountered:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to link vertex and fragment shaders.
    at Zt (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at t.createProgram (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at tf-core.esm.js:17
    at tf-core.esm.js:17
    at t.getAndSaveBinary (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at t.compileAndRun (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at t.conv2dWithIm2Row (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at t.conv2d (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at jt.runKernel.x (tf-core.esm.js:17)
    at tf-core.esm.js:17
```

My Javascript Code:

```
let classifier;

let img;

function modelReady(){
  console.log("Model Ready")
  try {
    classifier.predict(img, gotResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Model Error")
    console.error(error)
  }
}

function preload() {
  img = loadImage('./henry.jpg')
  classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet', modelReady);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(0)
  image(img, 0, 0);
}

// A function to run when we get any errors and the results
function gotResult(error, results) {
  // Display error in the console
  if (error) {
   console.error(error);
  }
  // The results are in an array ordered by confidence.
  console.log(results);
  console.log('Label: ' + results[0].label);
  console.log('Confidence: ' + nf(results[0].confidence, 0, 2));
}
```

Comment: sorry missed a hello at the beginning. "Hello Stackoverflow community"

Comment: Hi, I tried your code and it works. See a working version of your code here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ml5-imageclassifier